# How to check and remove '/' and '-' from a list of words at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have the following words in a list

```
listx=['info/base','tri-gen']
```

I am trying to remove both the '/' and '-' at the same time.

Currently I have two separate blocks of code (mentioned below) which achieve the above

```
    listx=['info/base','tri-gen']
    if '/' in listx:
        listmain= '/'.join(listx).split('/')
        listmain = list(filter(None, listmain))


    if '-' in listx:   
        listmain= '-'.join(listx).split('-')
        listmain = list(filter(None, listmain))
```

How do I achieve it in a single if condition or is there a way to include many conditions for e.g like below

```
'-','/'.join(listx).split('-','/')
```

Expected output

```
listx=['info base','tri gen']
```

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: Does this code currently run? I can't see where 'lisn' is defined.

Comment: Seriously who closed this question with a link to a tokanizer??? This is not a question about tokanizing.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, sorry was a typing mistake. corrected the 'lisn' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to do this is using the `re` module, which provides you with regex magic. Feel free to read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re
listx=['info/base','tri-gen']

[re.sub("\/|\-"," ",i) for i in listx]
```

Output:

```
['info base', 'tri gen']
```

**EDIT**

For your comment, I think you can get away without an if statement.

This regex will find all the words you need while ignoring the ones in parenthesis:

```
\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])
```

See it at work: https://regex101.com/r/YqhJDb/1

You can implement something like this:

`[" ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])", i)) for i in listx]`

Output:

`['info base', 'tri gen', 'century tech limited']`

Comment: @RidhimaKumar please check my updated answer

Comment: On your above solution. I had a doubt. When i have the list of type ['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management', '(', 'DCM', ')']. Your solution [" ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b(?![\(\w+\)])", i)) for i in listx] does not work. It returns ['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management', '', 'DCM', '']. While ideal output is ['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management']

Comment: This was not contained in your original example, try: `(?![\w\s]*[\)])\w+`

Comment: Yes, you are right this was not contained in original example. This issue just came to me when i tried on a list of the type i mentioned above. Your initial solution was perfect for my problem then. Coming to `(?![\w\s]*[\)])\w+` i tried it like below ( not sure i am doing it right) `[" ".join(re.findall(r"\b\w+\b((?![\w\s]*[\)])\w+)", i)) for i in listx]` and I am getting all blank elements `['', '', '', '', '', '']`. Also I hope that `(?![\w\s]*[\)])\w+` still removes \ and - as stated in the original question.

Comment: The above is giving me invalid syntax error with an ^ pointing at i). Also does the above expression remove '-' and '/' as well. When i add an extra bracket like this after i `[" ".join(re.findall(r"(?![\w\s]*[\)])\w+", i)) for i in listx`]` I get the output `['Dynamic', 'Case', 'Management', '', 'DCM', '']`

Comment: I am sorry, there was `)` missing. Your example was a list that did not contain splited items. See here: https://regex101.com/r/YqhJDb/2 . It works perfectly when using `listx = ["century tech limited (CTL)",
"tri-gen ( CTL )"]` with 
`[" ".join(re.findall(r"(?![\w\s]*[\)])\w+", i)) for i in listx]`